# Changing the color of the "i" in the bootstrap information glyphicon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the information glyphicon from bootstrap. Setting the color property with css changes the little circle colour that the "i" sits on...but i want to change the "i" color and i'm not sure how.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share some code please?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the background colour, then attempt to conceal the background edges using rounded corners, as follows:  (its not perfect, but achieves the 2 colour effect)

```css
.glyphicon-info-sign 
{
  color:yellow; 
  background-color: red; 
  border-radius: 50%; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Info-sign Glyph</h2>
      <p>Info-sign icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></p>    
      <p>Info-sign icon as a link:
        <a href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
        </a>
      </p>
      <p>Info-sign icon on a button:
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> Info
        </button>
      </p>
      <p>Info-sign icon on a styled link button:
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> Info
        </a>
      </p>  
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's transparent, so you cannot change the color of the "i". Imagine a colored disk with an i-shaped hole in it. But you can put another element with a background color behind it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use an `::after` pseudo-element to provide the `color`, the text of the `::before` pseudo-element being transparent.

The CSS for this is below, explanation in comments:

```
/* providing the default styles for the
   ::after pseudo-element: */
.glyphicon::after {
  /* We need to specify the 'content' (even if only
     an empty string) for the pseudo-element to
     show up on the page; as we only want to take
     advantage of its background-color we don't
     need to assign any content:*/
  content: '';

  /* to ensure that the pseudo-element takes the full
     space of the parent-element, which is sized
     according to its ::before pseudo-element, we
     position it absolutely, and align it to the
     borders of the parent element: */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  /* we want the background-color to show 'behind' or
     'under' the ::before pseudo-element, so we specify
     a lower z-index (which places it 'behind'
     the previous pseudo-element in the vertical 'stack': */
  z-index: -1;

  /* to style the pseudo-element as circular: */
  border-radius: 50%;

  /* to prevent its content spilling out, this is
     probably pointless, and entirely 'too' safe: */
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* using class-names according to their potential
   'themes' of use; here we specify the ::after
   pseudo-element of glyphicon elements which
   also have the 'warning' class: */
.warning.glyphicon::after {
  background-color: red;
}

/* As above, but here we style the pseudo-element
   of those glyphicons which also have the 'safe'
   class: */
.safe.glyphicon::after {
  background-color: limegreen;
}
```

```css
.glyphicon::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.warning.glyphicon::after {
  background-color: red;
}
.safe.glyphicon::after {
  background-color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign warning"></i>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign safe"></i>
```